# Is the swipe list pattern suitable for ecommerce

Tags: swipe, app

I'm working on an ecommerce app and it seems i need to perform 2-3 actions on an item on a list view without leaving the the screen. I'm wondering if the swipe list pattern (below) would be a suitable solution? This is common in email apps for deleting and archiving emails

[image]

Comment: What are the actions that the user would perform after swiping?

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally recommend against the swipe practice in general as it lacks indicators to tell the users what they are supposed to do. Comparatively a list with a "..." would be more apt.

Here's a quick sketch of what I meant

[image]

the " ... " also knows as "Ellipsis" is quite a conventional element that tells user there's more data / options / elements under the hood.

Comment: I completely disagree, when we're talking about mobile - swipes are a common action across both Android and iOS and are built into their design guidelines. I see no evidence that ellipses are a standard pattern.

Comment: Yes, swipes are a common action, but not commonly used for more actions on a list item. [This guideline page](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) focuses more on using swipe to navigate tabs / views. Infact there are examples where 3 vertical dots are used for more action options

Comment: I think swipes are commonly used on lists, the majority of email clients use it, and see guidelines here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists-controls.html. Vertical dots are very different to ellipses, and in the guideline you shared, it is only used as a menu element, not for actions.

Answer (score 0):

General UX / Interaction rule of thumb.

"Out of sight, out of mind"

Gestures are great, but how are you supposed to know they are there without a tip or guessing you can swipe the cell?

---

Use something more obvious if you want to ensure engagement (i.e. visible buttons on each cell)

[image]